# autodesk viewer fullscreen broken on iOS?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Noticed that when I go to view a 3d model on my iPhone (using the latest version safari or chrome), the full-screen button doesn't work. Anyone seeing this problem and has figured out a solution?

Public example you can try on your phone.... https://autodesk-forge.github.io/viewer-javascript-offline.sample/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and is being addressed by the Dev team. Stay tuned to the official [Forge blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog) for release notes of future versions of Viewer to keep tabs on the fix.

In the meantime one can work around by programmatically toggling the toolbar (there's no display cube on mobile either):

```
viewer.toolbar.setDisplay('none') //hide
viewer.toolbar.setDisplay('block') //show
```

You can come up with a button of your own as the control for this.